# Why is this function giving me a "Command Failed due to signal" error?

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

When I use this method my project won't compile, but whenever I delete it I get no error, I am confused why this is happening. This is what I am using

```
func animateNode(object: AnyObject){
    AnyObject.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        var objFrame = object.frame
        objFrame.origin.y -= objFrame.size.height

        object.frame = objFrame

    },completion: { finished in
        print("Animation Complete")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

Take a look at parentheses.

```
AnyObject.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    // Code ...
}) { finished in
    // Code ...
    print("Animation Complete")
}
```

I hope this can help you.